# how can i record JFR for jdk1.7_02 version

Tags: performance, profiling, jfr

I want to record JFR(Java Flight recorder) for an live application hosted on jdk1.7_02. I know that JFR was only introduced after jdk1.7_40. But can i do the same for jdk1.7_02 version by any means?? Please suggest if anybody has any idea. And if it is not possible, could somebody suggest me which open source profiling tool shall i use for application using jdk1.7_02 . Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first release with JFR is jdk1.7_04, but it lacks JVM events, so it has little practical use unless you are running WebLogic.

Answer (score 1):

JFR with 1.7.0_02 is impossible.
You could try VisualVM.